# ListView grid in React Native

Tags: listview, react-native

I'm building a simple app in React Native that fetches listings from a remote JSON source and displays them on screen.

So far, using the excellent [example](http://www.raywenderlich.com/99473/introducing-react-native-building-apps-javascript) here, I've managed to get the results to display using the ListView components in rows (i.e. 1 result per row, see screenshot). I need the results to display in a grid, i.e. 3 to 6 items per row, depending on the screen size and orientation.

What is the best way to get these results into a grid? Can I use ListView for this, or is that only for one-per-row results? I've tried playing around with flexbox styles but, since React doesn't seem to accept % values and ListView doesn't accept styles, I haven't yet had any success.

[image: This is how my listings are displaying at the moment - one per row.]

Answer (score 134, accepted):

You need to use a combination of [flexbox](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Flexible_boxes), and the knowledge that ListView wraps ScrollView and so takes on its properties. With that in mind you can use the ScrollView's `contentContainerStyle` prop to style the items.

```
var TestCmp = React.createClass({
    getInitialState: function() {
      var ds = new ListView.DataSource({rowHasChanged: (r1, r2) => r1 !== r2});
      var data = Array.apply(null, {length: 20}).map(Number.call, Number);
      return {
        dataSource: ds.cloneWithRows(data),
      };
    },

    render: function() {
      return (
        <ListView contentContainerStyle={styles.list}
          dataSource={this.state.dataSource}
          renderRow={(rowData) => <Text style={styles.item}>{rowData}</Text>}
        />
      );
    }
});
```

Just a ListView with some dummy data. Note the use of `contentContainerStyle`. Here's the style object:

```
var styles = StyleSheet.create({
    list: {
        flexDirection: 'row',
        flexWrap: 'wrap'
    },
    item: {
        backgroundColor: 'red',
        margin: 3,
        width: 100
    }
});
```

We tell the container we want items in a wrapping row, and the we set the width of each child object.

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for for something I'm doing! Thanks!

Comment: THANK YOU! This is exactly what I was hoping for, but didn't think existed.

Comment: Would anybody here know how to make this work when using `ListView` with sections?

Comment: How would you make the width of each child object equal to half of the parent container (for two equal sized children in each row)?  I tried flex: .5 for the children with flex: 1 for the parent listview, bit it fails.

Comment: For deferent height works? look like pinterest? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35017978/react-native-pinterest-style-with-flexbox

Comment: @MattH did you ever get your half-width items to work?

Comment: @ColinRamsay how would you make a grid with renderHeader as well? Because once renderHeader is applied, the contentContainerStyle does not work.

Comment: Awesome!!! This is just what I wanted. Didn't want to use a grid view component from github. I can confirm this also works for `FlatList`

Comment: Just a P.S This actually works for `View` too. ListView is not mandatory for this to work.

Answer (score 46):

ListView is now [deprecated](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/listview.html) and you should use [FlatList](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/flatlist.html) instead. FlatList has a prop called `numColumns` which is exactly what we want to create a scrollable grid.

For example:

```
const data = [
  {id: 'a', value: 'A'},
  {id: 'b', value: 'B'},
  {id: 'c', value: 'C'},
  {id: 'd', value: 'D'},
  {id: 'e', value: 'E'},
  {id: 'f', value: 'F'},
];
const numColumns = 3;
const size = Dimensions.get('window').width/numColumns;
const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  itemContainer: {
    width: size,
    height: size,
  },
  item: {
    flex: 1,
    margin: 3,
    backgroundColor: 'lightblue',
  }
});

function Grid(props) {
  return (
    <FlatList
      data={data}
      renderItem={({item}) => (
        <View style={styles.itemContainer}>
          <Text style={styles.item}>{item.value}</Text>
        </View>
      )}
      keyExtractor={item => item.id}
      numColumns={numColumns} />
  );
}
```

[image]

This [blog post](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/blog/2017/03/13/better-list-views.html) does a good job explaining the new features of FlatList.

Note: For some reason you have to use `keyExtractor` on the FlatList instead of the typical `key` prop on each item. Otherwise you'll get a warning. [Basic FlatList code throws Warning - React Native](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44545148/basic-flatlist-code-throws-warning-react-native)

Answer (score 37):

I'm adding this as an answer because overflow comments are hidden under Colin Ramsay's response: as of React Native 0.28, you also need `alignItems: 'flex-start',` in the listview styling or the flexWrap won't work. Thanks to Kerumen on codedump.io for this. So,

```
var styles = StyleSheet.create({
list: {
    flexDirection: 'row',
    flexWrap: 'wrap',
    alignItems: 'flex-start',
},
```

...with the rest as in Colin's response.

Comment: This is such an important comment. Thanks :)

Comment: @kwishnu you are a god !

Comment: I didn't answered on codedump. It was on StackOverflow ;)
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39313268/react-native-grid-view-flexbox-wrap-not-working/39316901

Comment: @kerumen - sure enough! Somehow that question ended up at https://codedump.io/share/cSuUKROA1Mmx/1/react-native-grid-view-flexbox-wrap-not-working , which was where I found it...at any rate, Thank you! It has helped a lot of people, and I've up-voted your answers

Comment: @kwishnu you are the best

Comment: You saved my life @kwishnu :D

Answer (score 7):

I had the same problem and I wrote a component that solves that problem, you can find it here: https://github.com/pavlelekic/react-native-gridview

Also, one other thing this component does is it makes sure that the items width is a whole number, so that the borders of items don't have antialiasing, they are clear and crisp.

Comment: @Pavle Lekic, thanks for writing that library.  I added an issue about renderHeader which doesn't size to the full width.

Answer (score 6):

Follow Colin Ramsay's answer. And if you want half width for each item, try this way.

```
...
import { Dimensions } from 'react-native'; 
const { width, height } = Dimensions.get('window');
const gutter = 0; // You can add gutter if you want
...


const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  item: {
    width: (width - gutter * 3)/2,
    marginBottom: gutter,
    flexDirection: 'column',
    alignSelf: 'flex-start',
    backgroundColor: '#ff0000',
  },
  list: {
    flexDirection: 'row',
    justifyContent: 'space-between',
    flexWrap: 'wrap',
    paddingHorizontal: gutter,
  },
});
```

Comment: I messed around a long time before stumbling to your answer down here. Thanks a ton for this!

Answer (score 2):

use FlatList instead of Listview in react-native. it has more value added feature and better performance. [checkout the example here](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/flatlist.html)

Answer (score 1):

You can use FlatList and set numColumns to obtain the result which is the same with grid

Answer (score 0):

Check the following example using **FlatList** component of **React Native** to support infinite scrolling with an excellent performance:

```
//Resize the grid
onLayout = (event) => { 
  const {width} = event.nativeEvent.layout;
  const itemWidth = 150
  const numColumns = Math.floor(width/itemWidth)
  this.setState({ numColumns: numColumns })
}

render() {
  return (
    <Content 
     contentContainerStyle={{flex:1, alignItems: 'center'}}
     onLayout={this.onLayout}>
       <FlatList
        data={this.state.products}
        keyExtractor={(item, index) => index}
        key={this.state.numColumns}
        numColumns={this.state.numColumns}
        renderItem={({item}) => 
          <ListThumb //Custom component, it's only an example.
           navigation={navigation}
           brand={item.brand}
           price={item.price}
           imageSource={item.image_link}/>
        }
     />
   </Content>
  )
}
```

The example looks like

[image]

Best regards, Nicholls

Answer (score 0):

**ScrollView** with **contentContainerStyle prop** worked for me

```
        <ScrollView contentContainerStyle={{ flexDirection: "row", flexWrap: "wrap", alignContent: "center",}}>
            {user.posts.map((post, index) => (
                <Image
                    source={require(post.uri)}
                    key={index}
                    style={{ width: 100, height: 100 }}
                />
            ))}
        </ScrollView>
```