# Responsive grid in React Native & Flex

Tags: flexbox, react-native

I'm want to create the simplest two column grid ListView

```
item | item
item | item
```

I saw this post about creating the grid and that worked - 
[ListView grid in React Native](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29394297/listview-grid-in-react-native)

I couldn't understand how to make my grid responsive? 
How can I set the size of the item to 50%?

I know it is a new language but I wish it could have some more detailed guides / documents.

Comment: I've just run into the same issue, did you ever find an answer to this?

Answer (score 44):

I just had to do that and I could solve it with simple react Views and the [flexWrap](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/layout-props.html#flexwrap) rule.

Parent view

```
{ flex: 1, flexDirection: 'row', flexWrap: 'wrap'}
```

Child View (Items)

```
{ width: '50%' }
```

Hope that this might help someone!

Comment: setting the child's width to a fixed percentage helped solve my issue of getting the items to evenly take up the space, thanks!

Comment: In the Child View it should be `{ flexBasis: '50%' }` not compulsory but recommended

Answer (score 4):

It's very simple, Use flex box, In your render method return view contains rows, and use for loop for putting data.

```
const rowData=[];

render() {
    return <View style={styles.container}>{rowData}</View>;
}

for (let objectData of newArray) {
    rowData.push(this.renderRowView(objectData));
}

renderRowView(objectData) {
    return(
        <View style={styles.mainContainer}>
            <View style={styles.leftView}></View>
            <View style={styles.rightView}></View>
       </View>
   );
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    mainContainer: {
        flex:1,
    },
    leftView: {
        flex:1,
    },
    rightView: {
        flex:1,
    }
});
```

I have not run this code but hope it works for you!!!

Comment: Harish Pathak,please refer my question on the below link-------------https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44386595/creating-a-gridview-from-listview-in-reactnativewithout-using-libraries -------iam sure you can answer this

Answer (score 4):

You can achieve this easily by using [react-native-easy-grid](https://github.com/GeekyAnts/react-native-easy-grid) library.

As it is a 2X2 layout, you can use it the following way. First import the library

```
import {Grid,Row,Col} from 'react-native-easy-grid'
```

**Code:**

```
 export default class StackOverflow extends Component {
constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    const ds = new ListView.DataSource({
        rowHasChanged: (r1, r2) => r1 !== r2
    });
    this.state = {
        dataSource: ds.cloneWithRows(["item"])
    };
}

render() {
    return (
        <View style={{ flex: 1, padding: 50 }}>
            <ListView
                dataSource={this.state.dataSource}
                renderRow={rowData => (
                    <Grid>
                        <Row style={styles.container}>
                            <Col
                                style={[
                                    styles.container,
                                    { backgroundColor: "yellow" }
                                ]}
                            >
                                <Text>{rowData}</Text>
                            </Col>
                            <Col
                                style={[
                                    styles.container,
                                    { backgroundColor: "green" }
                                ]}
                            >
                                <Text>{rowData}</Text>
                            </Col>
                        </Row>
                        <Row style={styles.container}>
                            <Col
                                style={[
                                    styles.container,
                                    { backgroundColor: "skyblue" }
                                ]}
                            >
                                <Text>{rowData}</Text>
                            </Col>
                            <Col
                                style={[
                                    styles.container,
                                    { backgroundColor: "orange" }
                                ]}
                            >
                                <Text>{rowData}</Text>
                            </Col>
                        </Row>
                    </Grid>
                )}
            />
        </View>
    );
}
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
container: {
    alignItems: "center",
    justifyContent: "center"
}
});
```

**The result would be this :**
[image]

**Explaination:**
I created a 2X2 layout using the react-native-easy-grid library using the components Grid, Row, Col. The beauty is you need not even mention any flexDirection attributes, it just works. Then, I passed this component to the renderRow prop of ListView element.

Comment: Just tweak the data source array according to your data, and change the required col with the index of the array e.g. : <Col>{rowData[1] }</Col>

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44386595/creating-a-gridview-from-listview-in-reactnativewithout-using-libraries---------    please answer my question on this link

Answer (score 2):

try setting the same flex value on both items so they would grow equally