# ListView grid on renderScrollComponent in React Native

Tags: listview, grid, react-native

My question is essentially the same as [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29394297/listview-grid-in-react-native). I got the grid view working on a simple `ListView` (like in the linked question), but I couldn't get it working when using a `renderScrollComponent`.

My code looks like this:

```
<ListView
  ref="ListView"
  contentContainerStyle={styles.list}
  dataSource={ this.state.dataSource }
  renderRow={this.renderCategories}
  renderScrollComponent={props => (
<ParallaxScrollView
    *start of parallax component*
```

Stylesheet:

```
list: {
  flexDirection: 'row',
  flexWrap: 'wrap'
},
item: {
  flexDirection: 'row',
  margin: 3,
  width: 120
},
```

The moment I comment out the `renderScrollComponent`, the grid works fine. So my question is how can I make a grid work inside a `renderScrollComponent`? Do I have to apply specific style somewhere?

(Note I'm using [this](https://github.com/jaysoo/react-native-parallax-scroll-view) repo for a parallax view in `renderScrollComponent`.