# React Native: How to apply ListView's contentContainerStyle to renderRow() to create grid while having renderHeader()?

Tags: javascript, ios, react-native, reactjs

I am trying to follow this: [ListView grid in React Native](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29394297/listview-grid-in-react-native) but with renderHeader() as well. When I have both renderHeader() and renderRow() with the

```
contentContainerStyle={{flexDirection: 'row', flexWrap: 'wrap'}}
```

, the whole ListView is affected, shifts left, and the renderRow() disappears.

But when I take out the renderHeader(), it creates the grid of renderRow() perfectly without any issues. So how can I go about using ListView's contentContainerStyle only to affect renderHeader() to create the grid, and also have renderHeader() as well?

```
return (
  <View style={{flex: 1}}>
    <ListView
      contentContainerStyle={{flexDirection: 'row', flexWrap: 'wrap'}}
      dataSource={this.state.dataSource}
      renderRow={this.renderRow.bind(this)}
      renderHeader={this.renderHeader.bind(this)}
    />
  </View>
);
```

Thank you in advance!

Comment: @ColinRamsay What may be the issue?

Answer (score 1):

At the moment, `ListView` sticks everything in a `<ScrollView contentContainerStyle>{renderHeader}{renderRow}{renderRow}{renderFooter}</ScrollView>` view structure. Keeping that in mind will help explain the formatting issues you see.

I think the best option at the moment, is to mark your header's style with `{width: Dimensions.get('window').width}`, to ensure that it uses up a full row (or whatever the width of your `<ListView>`.

I'm still having issues with this as I use `{alignSelf: 'center'}` on my `ListView` contents, and so the size of the header will affect/change the alignment of the renderRow contents too. But if you're not doing that, you shouldn't have any issue with it.