# React Native - iOS Collection View

Tags: ios, react-native, uicollectionview

Which approach should I use in React Native where I need to implement a horizontal scroll like collection view? The look and feel are needed to be exactly similar to the native iOS `UICollectionView`.

Answer (score 5):

You can use both `FlatList` and `ScrollView`. You just need to style your list in a correct way, for example, something like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29395686/4496128) to create a grid. Check [UIExplorer](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/tree/master/Examples/UIExplorer) to see how basic components work.

Answer (score 3):

You can use the ListView component, make sure you set the horizontal property.

```
<ListView horizontal={true}
style={{flex:1}}
dataSource={this.state.dataSource}
renderRow={(data) => <Row/>}/>
```

Also, you can follow this [link](https://medium.com/@talkol/recycling-rows-for-high-performance-react-native-list-views-628fd0363861) for reusable cells.