# React Native Grid View: Flexbox wrap not working

Tags: ios, gridview, reactjs, react-native

There seems to be a bug in React Native 0.32. The following code is working fine in 0.20 and 0.24, as you can see in the RN Play link.

https://rnplay.org/apps/W5k6Xg

```
'use strict';

var React = require('react');
var ReactNative = require('react-native');
var {
  AppRegistry,
  ListView,
  StyleSheet,
  Text,
  View,
  Image
} = ReactNative;

var GridLayoutExample = React.createClass({

  getInitialState: function() {
    var ds = new ListView.DataSource({rowHasChanged: (r1, r2) => r1 !== r2});
    return {
      dataSource: ds.cloneWithRows([
        { name: 'John', image: 'https://d30y9cdsu7xlg0.cloudfront.net/png/619232-84.png' },
        { name: 'Joel', image: 'https://d30y9cdsu7xlg0.cloudfront.net/png/619230-84.png' },
        { name: 'James', image: 'https://d30y9cdsu7xlg0.cloudfront.net/png/619168-84.png' },
        { name: 'Jimmy', image: 'https://d30y9cdsu7xlg0.cloudfront.net/png/619130-84.png' },
        { name: 'Jackson', image: 'https://d30y9cdsu7xlg0.cloudfront.net/png/619098-84.png' },
        { name: 'Jillian', image: 'https://d30y9cdsu7xlg0.cloudfront.net/png/618793-84.png' },
        { name: 'Julie', image: 'https://d30y9cdsu7xlg0.cloudfront.net/png/618803-84.png' },
        { name: 'Devin', image: 'https://d30y9cdsu7xlg0.cloudfront.net/png/618706-84.png' }
      ])
    };
  },

  render: function() {
    return (
      // ListView wraps ScrollView and so takes on its properties.
      // With that in mind you can use the ScrollView's contentContainerStyle prop to style the items.
        <ListView contentContainerStyle={styles.list}
          dataSource={this.state.dataSource}
          renderRow={this._renderRow}
        />
    );
  },

  _renderRow: function(rowData: string, sectionID: number, rowID: number) {
    return (
        <View>
          <View style={styles.row}>
            <Image style={styles.thumb} source={{uri: rowData.image}} />
            <Text style={styles.text}>
              {rowData.name}
            </Text>
          </View>
        </View>
    );
  }
});


var styles = StyleSheet.create({
  list: {
    justifyContent: 'center',
    flexDirection: 'row',
    flexWrap: 'wrap',
    backgroundColor: "blue"
  },
  row: {
    justifyContent: 'center',
    padding: 5,
    width: 100,
    height: 100,
    backgroundColor: '#F6F6F6',
    borderWidth: 1,
    borderColor: '#CCC',
    alignItems: 'center'
  },
  thumb: {
    width: 64,
    height: 64
  },
  text: {
    marginTop: 5,
    fontWeight: 'bold'
  }
});

AppRegistry.registerComponent('SampleApp', () => GridLayoutExample);
```

Expected Output (as you see on RNPlay w/ react native 0.24.1):

[image: Expected result]

What I'm seeing (React native 0.32):

[image: Wrong result. Can only see 3 cells and rest of them aren't wrapping]

Please help me figure this out.

Comment: So the following images just disappear ?

Comment: Yep. Seems so. @kerumen's answer works.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You should add `alignItems: 'flex-start'` to your `list`'s style.

```
list: {
  justifyContent: 'center',
  flexDirection: 'row',
  flexWrap: 'wrap',
  alignItems: 'flex-start',
  backgroundColor: "blue"
},
```

There was a breaking change in [React Native 0.28](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/releases/tag/v0.28.0) that changed the behaviour of `flex-wrap`:

> Due to performance tweaks `flexWrap: wrap` no longer works together with `alignItems: 'stretch'` (the default). If you use `flexWrap: wrap` you probably will want to add the `alignItems: 'flex-start'` style as well.

Comment: it works! this is surprising this is not documented.

Comment: if possible can you answer this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63245374/is-there-any-possibility-to-know-if-the-view-is-wrapped/63246306#63246306)