# is there any possibility to know if the View is wrapped

Tags: react-native, view, flexbox

I have a `View` as below

```
<View style={{width: '60%', flexDirection: 'row', flexWrap: 'wrap'}}>
    { .....}
    { .....}
<View>
```

if the items in the `View` are able to be rendered in the single line other wise `View` will be expanded to second line accordingly.

Here my doubt is , Is there any way to know programatically that `View` is wrapped?

Answer (score 0):

You can create reference to View and check its styles in its properties. Check here for how to create element reference https://reactjs.org/docs/refs-and-the-dom.html

Comment: created a ref and consle.logged it. it's just showing the all the props of View, but now way to find if the view is wrapped

Comment: check for style prop

Comment: i checked it....it showing all props as true...no matter whether the particular props is used or not.that is where i got stuck an dconfused