# Children overflow when using space-between inside container with flexWrap (React-Native)

Tags: react-native, flexbox

Just noticed a very weird behavior when using flexWrap on React-Native and wanted some help to understand if there's any explanation for that.

In summary:

I have a horizontal container that uses flexWrap, with two vertical child containers that will have two squares inside each. The squares have different heights. If I use space-between in the vertical child containers with flexWrap in the horizontal container, the children will overflow. If I remove flexWrap, things work correctly.

This problem *doesn't* happen on react-native-web, but happens on Android and iOS.

Expo with code: https://snack.expo.dev/fHKKvLlew

- Without `flexWrap` (expected behavior, works correctly)

```
    <View style={{ backgroundColor: 'purple', flexDirection: 'row' }}>
      <View style={{ borderWidth: 1, borderColor: 'white', justifyContent: 'space-between' }}>
        <View style={{ backgroundColor: 'red', height: 100, width: 100 }} />
        <View style={{ backgroundColor: 'green', height: 100, width: 100 }} />
      </View>
      <View style={{ borderWidth: 1, borderColor: 'white', justifyContent: 'space-between' }}>
        <View style={{ backgroundColor: 'blue', height: 150, width: 100 }} />
        <View style={{ backgroundColor: 'yellow', height: 150, width: 100 }} />
      </View>
    </View>
```

[image: Without flexWrap]

- With `flexWrap` (unexpected behavior)

```
    <View style={{ backgroundColor: 'purple', flexDirection: 'row', flexWrap: 'wrap' }}>
      <View style={{ borderWidth: 1, borderColor: 'white', justifyContent: 'space-between' }}>
        <View style={{ backgroundColor: 'red', height: 100, width: 100 }} />
        <View style={{ backgroundColor: 'green', height: 100, width: 100 }} />
      </View>
      <View style={{ borderWidth: 1, borderColor: 'white', justifyContent: 'space-between' }}>
        <View style={{ backgroundColor: 'blue', height: 150, width: 100 }} />
        <View style={{ backgroundColor: 'yellow', height: 150, width: 100 }} />
      </View>
    </View>
```

[image]

Anyone knows why the result is not the same when using flexWrap, given that there's still a lot of space available? And why children overflows?

Seems to be a bug (specially because it works fine on web). If so, any idea of a workaround that could result on similar results?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I test the code using **codesandbox** and I am not able to replicate the problem:

[image]

[image]

Perhaps there is sometime else causing the problem.

EDIT:

As mentioned, this behavior happens just for react native mobile, not for react native web, one way to get around this is by adding:

```
alignItems: 'flex-start'
```

[image]

As described in this [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39313268/react-native-grid-view-flexbox-wrap-not-working/39316901) post:

> Due to performance tweaks flexWrap: wrap no longer works together with alignItems: 'stretch' (the default). If you use flexWrap: wrap you probably will want to add the alignItems: 'flex-start' style as well.

So to replicate your configuration you may try:

```
<View style={{ alignItems: "flex-start", backgroundColor: 'purple', flexDirection: 'row', flexWrap: 'wrap' }}>
  <View style={{ alignSelf: "stretch", borderWidth: 1, borderColor: 'white', justifyContent: 'space-between' }}>
    <View style={{ backgroundColor: 'red', height: 100, width: 100 }} />
    <View style={{ backgroundColor: 'green', height: 100, width: 100 }} />
  </View>
  <View style={{ borderWidth: 1, borderColor: 'white', justifyContent: 'space-between' }}>
    <View style={{ backgroundColor: 'blue', height: 150, width: 100 }} />
    <View style={{ backgroundColor: 'yellow', height: 150, width: 100 }} />
  </View>
</View>
```

[image]

Comment: I think that code sandbox uses react-native-web by default. The issue probably happens only on native. Got an expo link and indeed, it works on web, but not on ios: https://snack.expo.dev/fHKKvLlew

Comment: Yes, I tested it on android, and I can confirm that there is a different behavior.

Comment: Thanks for helping, Mateo. The problem though is that I need to have stretch in the parent (default) so that children are affected by space-between. So flex-start in the parent will not help in my case.

But great that you found the original stuff. God, it's been around since 0.28!

Comment: Unfortunately, if you use flexWrap, you should change the default alignItems: 'streach' Maybe you can give me some more information about what you want to do. That way, I can try to help.

Comment: Its exactly that but instead of views I have some other components inside. Your answer is cool, with align self, I'll try that. If that doesn't work, fortunately I can also set some fixed heights to mitigate. Thank you!