# Why is this ListView only showing 10 items?

Tags: listview, react-native

(I know there are sites for sharing reactnative examples but I have not been able to find them via google; "react native share code" just comes up with the code for the sharing button, same for "example" -- what's a good site to use for this?)

I have a listview (thanks to this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29395686/30946), credit to @colin-ramsay). What I'd like to do is put some items inside of each listview and get them to align inside of their containers (a checkbox and a label on the same line). But I can't get that far because I can't figure out why this array of 20 items is only showing 10 items.

The alert shows 20 items (0-19) when it fires off.

Code:

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import {View, Text, StyleSheet, ListView} from 'react-native';

var styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container:{
    marginTop:65,
    margin:10, backgroundColor:"#DDDDEE"
  },
  list:{
    height:400,
    marginTop:40,
    flexDirection:'row',
    flexWrap:'wrap', justifyContent:'center', alignItems:'flex-start'
  },
  item:{
    alignItems:'flex-start',
    backgroundColor:'red', width:40, height:40, margin:3, padding:3,
    justifyContent:'center', alignItems:'center'
  }
});

class TestCmp extends Component {

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    var ds = new ListView.DataSource({rowHasChanged:(r1, r2) => r1 !== r2});
    var data = Array.apply(null, {length:20}).map(Number.call, Number);
    alert(data);
    this.state = {dataSource:ds.cloneWithRows(data)};
  }

  render() {
    return (

      <ListView contentContainerStyle={styles.list} dataSource={this.state.dataSource} renderRow={
        (rowData) => {
          return (
            <View style={styles.item}>
              <Text>{rowData}</Text>
            </View>
          )
        }
      }/>
    );
  }
}

export default class TestPage extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <TestCmp/>
      </View>
    )
  }
}
```

What happened to the other 10 items? I've tried using the inspector and changing the height of the container and nothing has worked.

[image: IOS screen shot]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

ReactNative ListView component calculates how many rows to render on initial component mount using [initialListSize](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/listview.html#initiallistsize) property. By default the `initialListSize` is set to 10.

For reference, See the below function from ReactNative [ListView](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/blob/0.37-stable/Libraries/CustomComponents/ListView/ListView.js#L292) source code,

```
  var DEFAULT_INITIAL_ROWS = 10;      
  getDefaultProps: function() {
    return {
      initialListSize: DEFAULT_INITIAL_ROWS,
      pageSize: DEFAULT_PAGE_SIZE,
      renderScrollComponent: props => <ScrollView {...props} />,
      scrollRenderAheadDistance: DEFAULT_SCROLL_RENDER_AHEAD,
      onEndReachedThreshold: DEFAULT_END_REACHED_THRESHOLD,
      stickyHeaderIndices: [],
    };
  }
```

If you want to make ListView render **all items by default** then you can make use of `initialListSize` property in ListView component like below code

```
<ListView contentContainerStyle={styles.list}
                initialListSize={20}
                dataSource={this.state.dataSource} renderRow={
        (rowData) => {
          return (
            <View style={styles.item}>
              <Text>{rowData}</Text>
            </View>
          )
        }
      }/>
```

Comment: Well that's completely goofy. That container is huge -- why would it decide to just randomly only display some of the items when the page is completely empty otherwise? Would I be better off just using `Array.map` with a `View` element? Seems simpler and doesn't have funny rules.

Comment: Yes. If number of elements are not much there is no reason to use ListView.

Comment: Main benefit of using ListView is render optimizations so setting `initialListSize` to item count makes it absolutely useless. For complex list items even 10 initial renders may be enough to make ui unresponsive.

Answer (score 0):

ListView determines visible rows based on item height (for vertical list) or item width (for horizontal list). You have vertical list (`horizontal={false}`) so for ListView you layout looks like this:

[image]

And ListView render 10 items because it is minimal render count by default (`initialListSize`).

You should manually place items in rows and render rows in ListView or search any grid view component.