# Create a grid eith react native

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I am trying to display element in a grid. Each line should contain as much as possible of elements depending on the screen size. I found a similar [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29394297/listview-grid-in-react-native/29395686#29395686) in the forum but the code seems old and I am very new with react native, I was not able to run it. Can you please help me? This is my current code

```
    export default class Container extends Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    const ds = new ListView.DataSource({rowHasChanged: (r1, r2) => r1 !== r2});
    this.state = {
      dataSource: ds.cloneWithRows(['row 1', 'row 2']),
    };
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <ListView
        dataSource={this.state.dataSource}
        renderRow={(rowData) => <Text>{rowData}</Text>}
      />
    );
  }
}
```

I get an error on the line `dataSource={this.state.dataSource}` : `undefined is not an object (evaluating 'new _reactNativeElements.ListView.DataSource`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to make sure you are importing `ListView` from `react-native`

```
import { ListView } from 'react-native'
```

The error states that `ListView` is `undefined`.

Note that it's deprecated and you should use FlatList instead.

> DEPRECATED - use one of the new list components, such as FlatList or
>   SectionList for bounded memory use, fewer bugs, better performance, an
>   easier to use API, and more features. [Check out this blog post for](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/blog/2017/03/13/better-list-views.html)
>   [more details.](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/blog/2017/03/13/better-list-views.html)