# react native horizontal list view with no scroll. How to wrap item?

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-native-listview

I'm showing items in list. I don't want to use horizontal scroll view but how can I wrap items such that they don't fall out of the screen? Just as we have FlowLayout in android.[the picture shows the third item in first row is half out of the screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uJjcF.png)

```
<List  horizontal={true} 
                            scrollEnabled={false}
                            style={{flexWrap: "wrap"}}
                            dataArray={articleData.Types}
                              renderRow={(Type) =>
                                <ListItem style={{borderBottomWidth: 0}} content>
                                    <Button rounded>
                                    <Text>{Type.Name}</Text>
                                    </Button>
                                </ListItem>
                            }>
                            </List>
```

Comment: Resolved using this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29394297/listview-grid-in-react-native

Comment: Any other better solution?

Answer (score 1):

Could use Views to achieve this:

```
<View style={styles.wrapContainer}>
    {DATA.map(data => {
      return (
        <View style={styles.buttonContainer} >
          <Button title={data.name}/>
        </View>
      )})
    }
  </View>
```

[Working Example](https://snack.expo.io/@tnr_c/wrappedbuttons)