# Create a two row listView

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I want to create a two row list. This is the result I want to achieve

[image]

I tried to use flatList with this code

```
    <FlatList
    style={styles.list}             //<-- This Line
    numColumns={2}                                  //<-- And this one
    data={[{key: 'row1'}, {key: 'row2'},{key: 'row3'},{key: 'row4'}]}
    renderItem={({item}) => 
    <View>
    <Text>{item.key}</Text>
    </View>
  } />
```

But I got his result

[image]

I also tried to put the width of each item to the half of the screen width with this code

```
<View style={{width: width /2}}>
<Text>{item.key}</Text>
</View>
```

But it dose not work when the device orientation changes.

What I want to achieve is to create a virtual table that have the width of the screen and put the text in the beginning of each cell. Something like this

```
+------------------------------+-----------------------------+
| item 1.                      | item 2.                     |
+------------------------------+-----------------------------+
| item 3.                      | item 4                      |
+------------------------------+-----------------------------+
| item5                        | item 6                      |
+------------------------------+-----------------------------+
```

Do you know how to achieve that?

Comment: Had a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29394297/listview-grid-in-react-native) ?

Comment: Yes I alerady saw it but it didin't help me to solve the problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You simply have to add `flex:1` to your parent view inside of your `renderItem` prop. Like so

```
<FlatList
   style={{flex: 1}} //whatever style you had          
   numColumns={2}                                  
   data={[{key: 'row1'}, {key: 'row2'},{key: 'row3'},{key: 'row4'}]}
   renderItem={({item}) =>
       <View style = {{flex: 1}}>
           <Text>{item.key}</Text>
       </View>
   } 
/>
```